# smooth surjective map from lower dimensional manifold onto higher dimensional manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I'm thinking about whether there exists a **smooth surjective map $f: M^m \twoheadrightarrow N^n$ where both $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, and $\dim M = m < n = \dim N$**. (We might assume that $M$ and $N$ are boundaryless, although I don't think this is necessary.)

Intuition tells me the answer is no, since smooth manifolds and smooth maps between them ought to behave nicely. Things like space-filling curves are obviously excluded from this class of nice objects.

However, I find it hard to justify such a claim. In particular, I tried to approach from the measure of $M$ and $N$ but failed. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem). If $m<n$, the image of $f$ consists solely of critical values, and thus must have measure zero in $N$.

Note that the proof of Sard's theorem is extremely difficult, so you shouldn't feel too bad about not discovering it!

Comment: I do know Sard's theorem and have seen a proof of it (and I thought about applying it...), but the version I know is from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, so to apply it to $M$ and $N$, I need to go to the ambient space of $N$. But the measure of $N$ could be zero in the ambient space; that's why it wasn't clear to me how to proceed. However, obviously Sard's theorem also applies to general manifolds. Then it's crystal clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[Sard's theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem) tells us that the image has measure zero.

Comment: Looks like you're scooped :)

Comment: @KevinSayHi, if that is significant to you, you *can* check the times at which answers are posted.

Comment: Yeah I've already checked, you're later by one minute (less than one actually) so I accepted the other one.

Comment: @4ae1e1 no, he answered earlier actually :)