Lissajous curve with irrational argument
Can a lissajous curve with irrational argument such as $$x=\cos(t) \\ y=\sin(t\sqrt{2})$$ be used as a $1$ to $2$ mapping since for any two given $x$ and $y$ in a rectangular region, $-1$ to $1$ and $-1$ to $1$; a $t$ can be found such that $x$ and $y$ are generated by the curve. Then $x$ and $y$ can be used to solve for $t$ thus compressing the information from two numbers into one?

As far as I know, those curves with inconmensurable coefficients are dense in the square $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$. But that does not mean that they go through every point in the square.

If by "used as a 1 to 2 mapping" you mean that it fills the square, this cannot happen because of Sard's theorem. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773765/smooth-surjective-map-from-lower-dimensional-manifold-onto-higher-dimensional-ma

In particular, i think the point $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ is never reached, if i did my calculations correctly

Just to confirm @nelynx 's 2nd comment, $\sin(t)=\frac12$ implies that $t$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$. $\cos(t\sqrt{2})=\frac12$ implies that $t\sqrt{2}$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$. Together, these imply that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

I think at the point t=378.031, x and y are close to .5 and .5

Of course √2 is irrational, but there are ratios of integers which can approximate it and also approximate multiples of pi at the same time. For instance pi/2 is relatively close to √2 if you want a really coarse approximation. But you can get as accurate as you want
